# Ceiling Mount Power Cable Pass Through

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling

I am Looking for guidance on mounting a laser light in our daughter's office/room remodel to the ceiling, while providing a clean way to hide the power cable.  Some of the laser light devices come with a detachable cable, others do not.  Is it "up-to-code" to pass the power cable through the ceiling where it could connect with a 1-gang outlet box affixed to the attic rafter?

Here is an example I found that I might pass the power cable through...

[image: Speedport 2" Through Grommet White]

Then I would connect the power cable to an outlet like this:

[image: Attic Outlet]

If there is a better recommendation, please share!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Stick a box and receptacle in the ceiling and plug the thing in there

This is a job for an *old work* type box mounted in the ceiling, with a receptacle mounted in the old work box.  That way, you'll be covered under NEC 400.7(A) point 2 which allows flexible cord to be used to wire luminaires, instead of violating NEC 400.8 point 2 which prohibits running flexible cordage through building surfaces.

If your device doesn't have a plug on it, get a field-fit type of NEMA 5-15 plug from the hardware store and put that on the end of the cord.

Powering the receptacle then can be done using a chapter 3 wiring method (such as NM) run through the attic to a box where constant power (always-hot and neutral) are present, such as the receptacle box pointed out in your photo.